# Is there a bounded sequence $(e_n)$ such that $e_n \in E_n$ and that $(e_n)$ does not have any convergent subsequence?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Assume that

- $T:E\to E$ is a compact (bounded linear) operator, and
- $(\lambda_n)$ is a sequence of distinct eigenvalues of $T$.

Let $E_n$ be the corresponding eigenspace of $\lambda_n$. Then $(E_n)$ is a sequence of finite-dimensional subspaces of $E$ such that $E_n \cap E_m = \{0\}$ for all $n \neq m$.

> Is there a bounded sequence $(e_n)$ such that $e_n \in E_n$ for all $n$ and that $(e_n)$ does not have any convergent subsequence?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Which of the following did you mean to ask: (i) "Is it true that for **any** such $E$ and $T$ there is a bounded sequence $(e_n)$ such that $e_n \in E_n$ for all $n$ and that $(e_n)$ does not have any convergent subsequence?" and (i) "Is it true that for **some** such $E$ and $T$ there is a bounded sequence $(e_n)$ such that $e_n \in E_n$ for all $n$ and that $(e_n)$ does not have any convergent subsequence?"

Comment: @IosifPinelis I meant (i)...

Comment: If you mean (i) then you will need to impose some more conditions, to ensure that T has an infinite number of distinct eigenvalues...

Comment: @YemonChoi The existence of such sequence $(\lambda_n)$ is actually part of the assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is negative. Take a biorthogonal sequence $(x_n,x_n^*)$ in $E$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to some unit norm vector $x_0$. Set

$T=\sum_n 2^{-n} \|x_n\|^{-1} x_n^* \otimes x_n$.

Such a sequence exists in every infinite dimensional space. For example, in $\ell_2$ let $x_n = e_0 + n^{-1} e_n$, where $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is orthonormal, and $x_n^*$ is $\langle \cdot, n e_n \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: [yes for normal operators on Hilbert spaces.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_spaces) We can write any normal compact operator as $\sum_{n\geq 1} \lambda_n f_n g_n^*$ with $(f_n)$, $(g_n)$ orthonormal families and $\lambda_n \to 0$. A $\lambda\neq 0$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $N_\lambda = \{ n : \lambda_n = \lambda\}$ is non-empty, in which case the eigenspace is $\mathrm{Vect}(f_n : n\in N_\lambda) = \mathrm{Vect}(g_n : n\in N_\lambda)$. This means that eigenspaces associated to different eigenvalues are necessarily orthogonal. Given an infinite sequence of distinct eigenvalues, one can then easily find a sequence of eigenvectors from which no subsequence converges.

Comment: That would be the case only for normal compact operators, right ?

Comment: You are correct; wikipedia lacks the hypothesis... I have updated my answer. It does weaken it even more than before.